# How to copy the text from a dropdown?

Tags: jquery

How can I copy the text from a dropdown using jQuery?

```html
<select id="pass1" class="ddl">
  <option value="yes">YES</option>
  <option value="no">NO</option>
  <option value="NA">N/A</option>
</select>
```

I'm trying to copy the text which is being displayed in the dropdown using windows selection command in jQuery and copy to clipboard command.

I could copy the whole page and text of the form but i couldn't copy the select options (text in the dropdown).

Comment: When you say you want to copy the value, do you mean that you want to place the value in the clipboard of the PC?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$("#pass1 option:selected").text();` to get the value of the current selected `option`. After which you can do with the value whatever you want, in [How do I copy to the clipboard in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/400252/4417306) is an example how you can copy things to the clipboard.

Answer (score 0):

To copy the text use this, it will copy the text and print, also to the clipboard :

```js
$("#pass1").on('change',function(){
 $("p").html($( "#pass1 option:selected" ).text());
  value = $( "#pass1 option:selected" ).text()
     var $temp = $("<input>");
          $("body").append($temp);
          $temp.val(value).select();
          document.execCommand("copy");
          $temp.remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="pass1" class="ddl">
    <option value="yes">YES</option>
     <option value="no">NO</option>
    <option value="NA">N/A</option>
</select>

<h1>
Selected: 
</h1>
<p>

</p>
```